# JS Scroll Event not firing up

Tags: javascript, php, scroll, onclick

I've tried overwriting the scroll-to-id-event with a js-function I found online [(Smoothly scroll to an element)](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2/).

For unknown reasons it wont fire up. Js itself is correctly implemented, as I managed to output some text with `document.print('test');`

Im really really not into Js, so please be patient with me.

**Index.php:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MyWebsite</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />

        <!-- JS WORKS THIS WAY -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- FIRST TRY HERE -->
        <script src="jquery/onScroll.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" />
    </head>

    <body>  
        <!-- SECOND TRY HERE / also with <script type="text/javascript">-->
        <script>
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
            var target = $(this.href);
                if( target.length ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
        </script>

        <div id="header">
            <div id="header" class="image light">
                Description overlayed on image.
                <footer class="dark">
                    My footer
                </footer>
            </div>
            <div id="header" class="description">
                Another Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="register">
            Some Content.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**onScroll.js**

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) 
{
    var target = $(this.href);
        if( target.length ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

**Result:**
Nothing happens. Its jumping in the default way. Tested Chrome and Firefox.

I hope I wont get kicked off for this rather simple thing. ^^
Appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

**EDIT -> [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Wt2rp/17/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `target` variable. `this` refers to the DOM element so as mentioned in another answer, `this.href` returns the full href of the element. A better solution would be to use jQuery's `.attr` method to return the exact contents of the href attribute. E.g:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
            if( target.length ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
});
```

This way, you're setting `target` to a jQuery collection containing elements (one in this case) that match the selector inside the href e.g `#Second`

Here's a [working fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wt2rp/18/)

Comment: Working, at least in the fiddle, but thats a problem I can solve myself. Yours looks a bit better without string concatenations and splits. Thanks very much! Also for explaining :)

Comment: Hey one last thing: Is `$('html, body')` only working for html-files? Or doesnt it matter? Currently cant bring it to work inside my project. Everything saved as .php.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If it's not working in a PHP file check the browser console log for any errors or 404s

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line

```
var target = $(this.href);
```

Even though you set your href to be `#Second` in html, the browser sets the href to be the full path (ex: http://www.yoursite.com#Second). To just get your hash selector you could use something like this.

```
var target = $('#' + this.href.split('#')[1]);
```

Comment: With this change there isnt happening anything. The page isnt even scrolling down. Check the fiddle I posted. Also tried your solution there, nothing happens.

Comment: Picked Andys answer as he posted a solution without string-splits or concats. Anyway upvoted for a working solution. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes on your code and worked.
On your link to scroll to another div, i used:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-scroll-to="#Second" class="button">Scroll to Second!</a>
```

And on javascript code:

```
$('[data-scroll-to]').on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $(this).data('scroll-to');    
            if( target.length ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

Now, anytime you want to scroll something, just use `data-scroll-to="#something"` in your code an put `javascript:;` on href attribute just to prevent any onclick event on link.

Comment: I don't see the point in this. It completely breaks if JavaScript is disabled whereas keeping it in the `href` attribute degrades gracefully and allows the anchors to still work

Comment: Dude. When I got a broken wheel, dont tell me to buy a new car!

Comment: The point is to not to need to have a link specifically to use scroll. You can use anywhere!

Comment: And dude, buy a new car! :P